# sharing dataset between classess

Tags: c#, class, dataset

My incompetence forced me to use not "clean" solution in my project. I got an ADO dataset in a class and need to share it between winforms and other classess. In order to achieve it, I made the dataset as public member. When I was at the early project stage, I searched quite a lot over the internet, but haven't found satysfying answer. But now I got some additional time, and my project isn't to big, I'd like to do it right. Any hints?

Tanks,
Ray

Comment: Its totally unclear what you want to achieve. What does it mean "share dataset betwen winforms and other classes"?

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I'll try to be more specific. I got a class that implements some db related operations and has a DataSet member to hold the data. I want this DataSet to be the only data source for other classess in my project. I want it as much accessible as possible for other classess to avoid wasting system resources. Is this more descriptive?

Answer (score 1):

Try to answer to very generic quesiton: reading what you write, I wolud say that it's perectly good solution to make a public property of a class which you want acees in different parts of app. The only hint, that I could think of (only because it's not specified, which doesn't mean that it's not done in that way) have a DataSet in your specialized data access class.

Repeat, that question is too generic. May be if you secify something more detailed you will be given more concrete help on subject.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Create dataSet as a property, using get, set accessor. YOu can make it static, so it will be available without creating classes (or forms) new references.

Example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static DataSet myDataSet { get; set; }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();
    }
}

class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {      
        //fill dataSet (add new table and some example rows):
        DataTable table = new DataTable("table1");
        table.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
        table.Rows.Add("item 1");
        table.Rows.Add("item 2");

        Form1.myDataSet = new DataSet();
        Form1.myDataSet.Tables.Add(table);
    }
}

class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        //show dataSet results:
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataRow dr in Form1.myDataSet.Tables["table1"].Rows)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(dr[0].ToString());
        }
        //show:
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Mitja, indeed, marking dataset as static is a solution :)